# Select all by Category and ALL Sub-Categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an ad model that belongs_to a category and categories can nest within other categories (basically as deep as they want to go). Is there an easy way to fetch all ads from a category and all of that categories sub-categories?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for anyone that needed to know. This also includes only fetching ads by region (think craigslist or backpage):

```
(categories.map {|category| category.all_ads(regionid)}.flatten + ads).select {|item| item.region_id == regionid}
```